# Get list of struct names that are outside of 'package' and 'endpackage' optional strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7, python-re

I am trying to get struct names which are outside `package` and `endpackage` optional strings.
If there are no `package` and `endpackage` strings, then the script should return all the struct names.

This is my script:

```
import re

a = """
package new;

typedef struct packed
{
    logic a;
    logic b;
} abc_y;

typedef struct packed
{
    logic a;
    logic b;
} abc_t;

endpackage

typedef struct packed
{
    logic a;
    logic b;
} abc_x;

"""

print(re.findall(r'(?!package)*.*?typedef\s+struct\s+packed\s*{.*?}\s*(\w+);.*?(?!endpackage)*', a, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL))
```

This is the output:

```
['abc_y', 'abc_t', 'abc_x']
```

Expected output:

```
['abc_x']
```

I am missing something in the regex, but can't figure out what. Can someone please help me fixing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
\bpackage.*?\bendpackage\b|typedef\s+struct\s+packed\s*{[^{}]*}\s*(\w+);
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/U8rIbP/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  package                  'package'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  endpackage               'endpackage'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  typedef                  'typedef'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  struct                   'struct'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  packed                   'packed'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {                        '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }                        '}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;                        ';'
```

[**Python code**](https://tio.run/##pVA9C8IwEN3zK44uxlq6OBYRwVF0cTMqSXvVYExLeqKl9rfXqAWd9U3vON7HXVnTsbDjrtPnsnAEDhmTMIEgCFgp05M8IFi8JoxRXWKGOVTkLinBc4kZaxh4mOKgU5DJ16AS1oJU6b7@Q0teizbri/zuc/M@r4uctsSNrojn2hA6viwsRg7jXNtMGsPdQKg@Lg6nQn3Shbr38aIavQt48q4gqrDZ7Jp2G7aecnEdDZNBBDLy/4znq/VssRh6dN0D):

```py
print(list(filter(None,re.findall(r'\bpackage.*?\bendpackage\b|typedef\s+struct\s+packed\s*{[^{}]*}\s*(\w+);', a, re.DOTALL))))
```

**Results**: `['abc_x']`

Comment: @ Ryszard Czech, I tried the regex you provided, but I get output as: `['', 'abc_x']`

Comment: @Sweety `list(filter(None,re.findall(r'\bpackage.*?\bendpackage\b|typedef\s+struct\s+packed\s*{[^{}]*}\s*(\w+);', a, re.DOTALL)))`